# How do I replace frequently used new keyword with Spring calls 4 Unit testing?

Tags: java, spring

Clarification:

The legacy code wasn't Sprung completely ( see what I did there ) and also test coverage is low. We are working to improve it now but we see uses of the new keyword everywhere and this is going to ruin our unit isolation. I'd rather not wire in a ref to the Spring Context as that ties us pretty closely to Spring and I can't use PowerMock due to an Architects directive. What we've been doing is putting all calls to ***new*** in protected methods so we can override but shouldn't Spring be doing that and how do we get Spring to do it?  I can easily imagine creating an appropriately annotated method in a @Configuration annotated class with scope set to... hmmm.. nothing at all? That should mean that the class generates a new one on every call. Question is, how do I use that in my subject under test?

Comment: This question is undoubtedly going to get closed but I have to ask - what possible reason did an architect have for telling you not to use a ubiquitous mocking framework?

Comment: Yeah, this begs a lot of questions about the architect.  Why are you using Spring if you're not allowed to actually inject your dependencies?  Does the architect not understand the technology?  Why are you using it in production if you have reservations over it?

Comment: @christopher I would understand not encouraging the use of Powermock: most of the time, it's used precisely to make it possible to test code that does *not* use dependency injection (i.e. Instead of simply mocking dependencies and injecting them, it allows mocking constructors, static methods, etc.). So not using Powermock actually encourages the use of DI to make the code testable.

Comment: I didn't say we weren't injecting dependencies. Some of them are but we have cases where we are converting lists of objects, for example, into other objects and the new keyword is used there. New code is being written correctly but we still have to get our coverage up.